# R Shiny creating a list of menu Items and sub Items

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I am trying to create a `selectInput`with all of the available menu items on the sidebar but so far, can only get it to show the current menu selection.

Below is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

rm(list=ls())

header <- dashboardHeader()
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(id = "menuChoice",
              menuItem("Resources", tabName = "ResourcesMenu", icon = icon("leaf"),
                       menuSubItem("Filter Selection", tabName = "LayoutSubMenu", icon = icon("angle-double-right")),
                       menuSubItem("Test", tabName = "Test2", icon = icon("globe")),
                       menuSubItem("Test 3", tabName = "Test3", icon = icon("wrench"))
              ),
              menuItem("Trial Run", tabName = "TR", icon = icon("star"))
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  uiOutput("TabSelect")
)


ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$TabSelect <- renderUI ({
                     selectInput(inputId = "LoadTab", "Available Tabs",
                                 choices = c(input$menuChoice)  
                     )
  })



}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What I would like is for a `selectInput` to show `LayoutSubMenu, Test2, Test3, TR`. The name shown in the tab would be ideal as well `Filter Selection, Test, Test 3, Trial Run` as a seperate `selectInput`.

Comment: A global list containing the tabNames would be sufficient?

Comment: That's always my second option, just didn't know if there was a dynamic way to do it.